# Erro java.lang.NullPointerException em Conexão JDBC com WS + Postgres

Tags: java, web-service, postgresql, conexão, jdbc

Estou criando um WS que conecta a um DB PostgreSQL e realiza uma consulta numa única tabela.

Eu tento rodá-lo localmente, mas o problema é quando executo a aplicação dá o seguinte erro:

> Status do HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type: Relatório de exceção
>
> mensagem: Internal Server Error
>
> descrição: O servidor encontrou um erro interno ({0}) que o impediu de
>   atender esta solicitação.

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException causa-raiz

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Obs: Os rastreamentos de pilha completa da exceção e suas causas-raiz estão disponíveis nos logs de GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 .

Eu creio que não seja tão complexo, mas como não tenho experiência com a linguagem, estou tendo dificuldades.

Meus códigos são:

**DBConnection.java**

```
package br.com.dbconnection;

import br.com.findfriends.entidade.Friend;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBConnection {  

    private String databaseURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/wsfindfriends";  
    private String usuario = "postgres";  
    private String senha = "senhaPostgres";  
    private String driverName = "org.postgresql.Driver";  
    private PreparedStatement stmt = null;  
    private ResultSet rs = null;  
    public Connection conn = null;  

    public void DBConnection() {          
        try {  
            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();  
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, usuario, senha);  
            System.out.println("Conexão obtida com sucesso.");  
        }  
        catch (SQLException ex) {  
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());  
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());  
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());  
        }  
        catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("Problemas ao tentar conectar com o banco de dados: " + e);  
        }        
    }  

    public List<Friend> executeQuery(String query) {  
        try {  
            List<Friend> list = new ArrayList<Friend>();  
            this.stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(query);  
            this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery();              

            while (rs.next()) {  
                // criando o objeto Friend  
                Friend friend = new Friend();  
                friend.setId(rs.getInt("id"));  
                friend.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));  
                friend.setNome(rs.getString("fone"));  

                // adicionando o objeto à lista  
                list.add(friend);  
            }  
            this.close();  
            return list;  
        }  
        catch (SQLException e) {  
            throw new RuntimeException(e);  
        }  
    }  

    public void close(){  
        try {  
            this.stmt.close();  
            this.rs.close();  
            this.conn.close();  
        }  
        catch (SQLException e) {  
            throw new RuntimeException(e);  
        }  
    }      
}
```

**FindFriendsService.java**

```
package br.com.findfriends;

import br.com.dbconnection.DBConnection;
import br.com.findfriends.entidade.Friend;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("findfriends")  
public class FindFriendsService {  

    @Context  
    private UriInfo context;  

    /** 
     * Creates a new instance of FindFriendsService 
     */  
    public FindFriendsService() {  
    }  

    /** 
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of br.com.findfriends.FindFriendsService 
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String 
     */  
    @GET  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
    public String getJson() {  
        //TODO return proper representation object          
        DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection();  
        List<Friend> list = new ArrayList<Friend>();  
        list = dbc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM locationfriends");  

        Gson gson = new Gson();  
        return gson.toJson(list);          
    }  

    /** 
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of FindFriendsService 
     * @param content representation for the resource 
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource. 
     */  
    @PUT  
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
    public void putJson(String content) {  
    }  
}
```

**Friend.java**

```
package br.com.findfriends.entidade;

public class Friend {  

    private int id;  
    private String nome, fone;  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  

    public String getNome() {  
        return nome;  
    }  

    public void setNome(String nome) {  
        this.nome = nome;  
    }  

    public String getFone() {  
        return fone;  
    }  

    public void setFone(String fone) {  
        this.fone = fone;  
    }  
}
```

=====================================

**Edit:** Segue stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.dbconnection.DBConnection.executeQuery(DBConnection.java:51)
    at br.com.findfriends.FindFriendsService.getJson(FindFriendsService.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Por favor, cole o stack-trace num pastebin para nós, sem ele não dá pra saber o problema.

Comment: Onde você está hospedando seu webservice?

Comment: **+Edgar Muniz Berlinck**, não sabia o que era stacktrace, mas fiz uma pesquisa rápida e acho que descobri. Post atualizado. **+Math**, estou testando localmente apenas.

Comment: Qual é a linha 51 no seu `DBConnection.java`?

Comment: linha 51: this.stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(query);

Comment: Não foi lançada mais nenhuma exceção? Pois o erro está indicando que a variável `conn` não está referenciando um objeto, entretanto ela deveria ter sido inicializada no construtor, mas é possível que o construtor não tenha rodado por inteiro caso tenha ocorrido algum problema nele.

Comment: Não. Quando executo a aplicação dá o erro logo de cara sem lançar exceção.

Comment: Seu PostgreSQL está realmente executando na porta 8080? Por padrão essa é a porta do Glassfish. Na URL de conexão não é necessário colocar a porta, a menos que o PostgreSQL esteja rodando em outra porta que não seja a padrão.

Comment: ao executar a aplicação, acesso o webservice pela url: **http://localhost:8080/wsfindfriends/webresources/findfriends**. Caso eu tente acessar **http://localhost/wsfindfriends/webresources/findfriends**, retirando a porta **8080**, dá NotFound. Tem alguma relação?

Comment: Tem sim, para você acessar a aplicação você realmente deve acessar localhost:8080/SuaAplicacao, mas a URL da conexão com o banco é diferente, não é a mesma que se usa para acessar a aplicação.

Comment: como posso descobrir se essa URL está correta? E se não, como saber a url correta pra usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte:

**databaseURL**, está apontando para a porta do servidor de aplicação e não do servidor de banco de dados;

Então, **databaseURL** deve ser asssim:

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost/nomeDoSeuBancoDeDados`

Pois não é necessário colocar a porta na URL de conexão com o banco, pois quando não colocada a porta padrão é usada. É necessária apenas quando a porta é alterada e creio que não é o seu caso.

Para acessar sua aplicação continue usando:

`localhost:8080/wsfindfriends/webresources/findfriends`

Comment: Cara, foi isso mesmo. Tinha copiado o script de terceiros que estava setando essa porta, no fim foi apenas retirá-la. Obrigado! Que erro mais primário hein. T_T

Comment: Rsrsr. Que bom ter ajudado.